# How do I add WebView to one of the fragments

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add `WebView` to my android app. To do so, I'm following this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TUXui5ItBkM

If I put `Webview` in activity_main, the website is displayed, although this is not what I want.

I have 3 fragments, Livestream, NewsArticles and Settings. When I add `WebView` to the NewsArticles fragment like so:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

the app crashes. I'm not sure what the problem is. I don't seem to find any bugs/errors popup in android studio as well. This is the `MainActivity`'s code:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.loadUrl("https://www.alt-info.com");
```

I've internet traffic permission enabled as well.

Comment: This is what I found in logcat https://imgur.com/a/mxZhI9T

Comment: you need to initialize webView in fragment's code, where the <WebView> is, and move the code from MainActivity to there

Comment: You're correct. But now I'm unsure about how to actually implement the webView code because articlesFragment java file looks different and made me change findViewById to webView.findViewById.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a fragment, then you have to specify this:

Replace this following code

```
@Override public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,@Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_articles, container, false);
}
```

with this:

```
@Override public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,@Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_articles, container, false);
    webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
}
```

When you use fragments, you have to say "view.findViewById()". You have the add "view" in front of "findViewById" EVERY TIME you initialize an object.

Also, if the app crashes, there definitely is an error that should pop up in Android Studio. Click on "Logcat" once you run it and check for any red text.

Comment: I had to move webView code from MainActivity to ArticlesFragment, but in ArticlesFragment, I had this 
```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_articles, container, false);

    }```

Not sure how to add the code that you provided.

Comment: Try the solution now.